# Can I use TWO (or more) data sources in PineScript to calculate my own custom indicator?

Tags: pine-script

I'm looking to capture the difference between two different indicator outputs. Is this possible in PineScript? Or can we only leverage one input from another source?

Every time I try to add a second input(source) it limits the inputs of all dropdowns to the standard (OLHC, etc). I was expecting each dropdown to have their own list of all other indicators on my chart.

Answer (score 0):

You can only obtain one external data as source.

For external indicators to appear in an input widget's dropdown menu, only one `input.source()` call must be used in the script. If multiple calls are used, then no external indicator can be selected in any of the script's input widgets.